# Different behavior of __init__ method depending on order in code

Tags: python, list, class, stack, in-class-initialization

I have created a `unit` class to manage units of physical quantities the user will input with their corresponding numerical values. The `unit` class takes a string input, and saves data in the form of three arrays containing each the physical `units`, their `powers` and a correspondence list that matches the `k`th element in that list to the `correspondence[k]`th element in the `units` array. In other words, the `k`th element represents the `k`th power in the `powers` list and the `correspondence[k]` element is its matching unit.
Here is the definition of that class :

```py
class unit:
    units = []
    powers = []
    correspondance = []
    def __init__(self,input_string):
        try:
            assert(type(input_string)==str)
        except AssertionError:
            print(type(input_string))
        new_string = True
        new_number = True
        for element in input_string :
            if element.isdigit() or element == "-":
                new_string = True
                if new_number:
                    self.powers.append("")
                    new_number = False
                    self.correspondance.append(len(self.units)-1)
                self.powers[-1] += element
            else:
                new_number = True
                if new_string :
                    self.units.append("")
                    new_string = False
                self.units[-1] += element
```

What happens is that when I define two objects `p` and `q` . `q` seems to have an odd behavior. Despite having the same definition as `p` :

```py
p = unit("T")
print(p.units)
q = unit("T")
print(q.units)
```

***Output***

```
['T']
['T', 'T']
```

What is even strange is that when I change the order of `print()` functions I get yet another different output for the following code:

```py
p = unit("T")
q = unit("T")
print(q.units)
print(p.units)
```

***Output***

```
['T', 'T']
['T', 'T']
```

Comment: @InSync there's no mutable default argument here. The problem is that the OP uses a class attribute instead of an instance attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The variables `units`, `powers` and `correspondance` of your class are class varibales, meaning that they belong to the class. This means that if you make an instance of the class, it does not have its own copy of these list. Instead, there is only exactly one copy which belongs to the class iself and it shared between all instances of it. So if you change it in the `__init__` method, it will change for every instance of the class.

To fix this, you need to simply convert those class variables to instance varibles by initializing them inside the `__init__` method:

```py
    def __init__(self, input_string):
        self.units = []
        self.powers = []
        self.correspondance = []
```

Please use class variables only for constants that do not change.

Answer (score 1):

The variables *units*, *powers* and *correspondance* are class attributes. In simple terms this means that all/any instances of the *unit* class will share these variables. You probably want instance variables instead. You can construct those during __init__

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain the part that is confusing you, but be aware that the code needs correction in the other parts.

```
class unit:
    units = []
    powers = []
    correspondance = []
    ...
```

`units, powers and correspondence`, the way you put it in the code, are class variables, that is: they will be shared by all objects of that class.

When running the code, the class is evaluated only once, checking if it is valid python code. At this moment, the class variables (`units, powers and correspondence`) are defined, with values:

```
units = []
powers = []
correspondance = []
```

Whenever you create an object:

```
p = unit("T")
```

or

```
q = unit("T"),
```

the **new** method is called (constructor), and passes the object itself (self) to **init** (initializer)***. So each time an object is created, everything inside the **init** method will be called

So, when you create the object `p`, and run this line:

`self.units[-1] += element`,

the string `T` becomes part of the units class variable, being shared with all new objects that are created from there.

when you create the object `q`, passing the string `T`, it will again be called `self.units[-1] += element`, however, `self.units` already contains the element `T`, adding a new element in the last position (a new `T`).

So, if your goal is to reset these elements every time a new object is created, just pass `units, power, correspondence` into **init**

```
 def __init__(self, input_string):
     self.units = []
     self.powers = []
     self.correspondance = []

        ...
```

***NOTE: That's why the first parameter of every class initializer (**init**) is self